# yeoman call generator prompt from sub-generator

Tags: javascript, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I have `yo someGen`, that prompts few questions. one of the prompts, `someQuestion` is asking `would you like to use smthng?` and the user can choose from `smthng1`,`smthng2` or `no`.

I have a a sub generator `yo someGen:smthng` that do something else(`smthng1` or `smthng2`) , with regard to the answer from `someQuestion`.

Now if the user trying `yo someGen:smthng`, but earlier (in main gen) he answered `no`, I want to propmt `someQuestion` again. giving him the chance to decide `smthng` now, and then operate `yo someGen:smthng` according to the new answer, with the ability to regret and answer `no` again.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `yeoman-generator` configuration to store user choices. See the documentation http://yeoman.io/authoring/storage.html

Comment: Storing is not the issue - the question is - how can I use the prompt from main-gen - Do I need to write the code again, or can I use it as-is?

Comment: Either copy the code or create a function and call it... I mean, normal programming stuff right.